# Number of seconds from now() to Sunday midnight

Tags: php, time

In PHP how do I get the number of seconds from `now()` until the next Sunday at midnight?

I don't want the solution relative to a specific date, but just to the next Sunday.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$seconds = strtotime('next Sunday') - time();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
print strtotime('next Sunday') - time();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function secs_until() {
  $now = time();
  $next = strtotime("next Sunday midnight");
  return $next - $now;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as:

```
strtotime('next Sunday') - time()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$seconds = mktime(0,0,0, date("n"), date("j") + (7 - date("N")), date("Y")) - time();
```

That string will give you the diff in seconds from now to sunday morning at 12:00.  You can adjust the first 3 arguments in mktime() to give you a variable time of day (say 8:45 AM)